# Best approach to multi-language app with a lot of language-specific resources?

Tags: android, multilingual

The application is multi-language (10 languages or so) and it has a lot of audio files in multiple languages. This makes it too large to be one app, thou the logic is all the same. So we decided to separate app into 1 app for 1 language.

What is the best approach to maintaining such app? The logic will be the same, but only resources will change. Having 10 separate projects would be a waste of time.

Maybe to create 9 library projects holding only language-specific data?

Ideally, I would be able to make changes and then export EN version, then export ES, then FR version, etc.

Comment: Do you want your app to be offline? If possible, store the audio files on server and give links to the audio files. You can store the links in separate folders.

Comment: @Vera The app will be offline.

Comment: Please try the expansion pack.
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one library project, the logic project.

Then, create a project by each language with have the library project.

Other form is use any VCS, as GIT, and create a brach for each language.

EDIT:

Library projects:

If the logic is the library project, you can create the apks directly from language projects.

But I don't know if you need "dummy files" in logic project for references.

SVC:

You create the master (principal) brach for english (for example). After, you create a new branch "spanish". In this branch, you reemplace the english files by spanish files.

If you need modify the logic, back to master branch, modify the files, change to spanish branch and merge the changes. The merge only modify the lines changed in master and hold the spanish files.

Comment: Oh you mean the opposite way, logic is library. Have not thought about it. Also I have never considered GIT and its branches. What did you have in mind? Can you be more specific? Just edit your reply, better than adding comment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your best choice is to make each language resource pack downloadable as a separate unit (a zipped file).
So each user will download the app and then the language pack (strings, audio files, graphics, videos, ...).

Ideally, you'll update the main app only.
Then the language packs - only if needed.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this. But this bring extra concerns like storage locations and extra coding. Also the client is not keen to this approach.

Comment: Then you could give all the language packs at once (zipped) and just unzip the one they choose. But this would not solde the problem of the  combined weight of the app + resource packs.

Comment: Yes, audio files don't compress well.

Comment: Nor do videos or images... only strings do. But these can be distributed in the normal way (strings.xml in /res/values-xy).